# Discord.JS: Отправка картинки как буфер или Data URL

Tags: node.js, canvas, discord-api

Возможно ли отправить картинку, сгенерированную с помощью node-canvas сообщением в Discord.js, не сохраняя её, предварительно, на диск?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была связана с тем, что в версии 11.1.0 сломана функция, отправляющая буфер.
Она на вход получает `undefined`
[image: screenshot]

Проблема решилась обновлением до версии 11.3.2.

Comment: `let attachment = Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'image.png')
msg.channel.send(attachment)`